# iOS detect if user is on an iPad

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, ipad

I have an app that runs on the iPhone and iPod Touch, it can run on the Retina iPad and everything but there needs to be one adjustment. I need to detect if the current device is an iPad. What code can I use to detect if the user is using an iPad in my `UIViewController` and then change something accordingly?

Answer (score 606, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to check if a device is an iPad. This is my favorite way to check whether the device is in fact an iPad:

```
if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
{
    return YES; /* Device is iPad */
}
```

### The way I use it

```
#define IDIOM    UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()
#define IPAD     UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

if ( IDIOM == IPAD ) {
    /* do something specifically for iPad. */
} else {
    /* do something specifically for iPhone or iPod touch. */
}
```

### Other Examples

```
if ( [(NSString*)[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPad"] ) {
    return YES; /* Device is iPad */
}

#define IPAD     (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
if ( IPAD ) 
     return YES;
```

For a Swift solution, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27517536/2057171

Comment: The way you use it isn't as efficient as it could be. `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` is equivalent to `([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom)] ? [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] : UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)`. You might be better off caching the result somewhere: `BOOL iPad = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad; … if (iPad) …`.

Comment: I would use hasPrefix rather than isEqualToString in your last method. In this way the code works on the simulator as well.

Comment: Yes this will return iPad for the mini.

Comment: Swift: `if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad`

Comment: `#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` is never entered for me, using Xcode 6.3 compiling for iOS 8.2

Comment: Godawful use of macros. Great way to obfuscate your code.

Comment: @gnasher729 500+ people tend to disagree with you. Instead of the snarky comments, why don't you provide your own answer since you think you have a better way to do this.

Comment: Swift 4: `if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad`

Comment: WrightsCS: You already provided a better way right above the macro way...

Comment: Does it happen during compile time or run time?

Comment: @MarceloCantos Wish you could edit the answer to provide to include your comment

Answer (score 194):

In **Swift** you can use the following equalities to determine the **kind of device** on Universal apps:

```
UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
// or
UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad
```

**Usage** would then be something like:

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
    // Available Idioms - .pad, .phone, .tv, .carPlay, .unspecified
    // Implement your logic here
}
```

Comment: I'm Editing a link to your answer into the accepted answer. (This way you get credit too). Even though this is an objective-c question, alot of people viewing this question are coming from Google and may be searching for a Swift solution! :D

Comment: Thank you, @AlbertRenshaw. I thought so, too. :)
Btw: I don't think the intention of the question was to ask specifically for Objective-C, but for iOS (which was Obj-C at that moment). At least I would have expected to find the answer under this question for Swift as well.

Comment: Hi @sevensevens, thank you for your feedback. I just tried this out and it did work for me in XCode 7.2 targeting iOS 9 in the simulator. What version of XCode are you using? Maybe it doesn't work on older XCodes? The docs say `userInterfaceIdiom` is 'Available in iOS 3.2 and later.' so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Or could it be that you are running an iPhone only app on the iPad simulator? In that case, that would explain the confusion – but it should also behave this way on real devices, I think. As @Yunus Nedim Mehel points out in the comments of @Richards answer that situation will return `.Phone` instead of `.Pad`.

Comment: Sorry - had the simulator set to iPhone.  Gotta stop making changes at 2AM

Answer (score 38):

This is part of UIDevice as of iOS 3.2, e.g.:

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
```

Comment: idiom is generally better but if you are running an iphone app on iPad than this will return UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone.

Answer (score 25):

You can also use this

```
#define IPAD UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
...
if (IPAD) {
   // iPad
} else {
   // iPhone / iPod Touch
}
```

Answer (score 24):

`UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` only returns iPad if the app is for iPad or Universal. If its an iPhone app running on an iPad then it won't. So you should instead check the model.

Answer (score 18):

I found that some solution didn't work for me in the Simulator within Xcode. Instead, this works:

#### ObjC

```
NSString *deviceModel = (NSString*)[UIDevice currentDevice].model;

if ([[deviceModel substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)] isEqualToString:@"iPad"]) {
    DebugLog(@"iPad");
} else {
    DebugLog(@"iPhone or iPod Touch");
}
```

#### Swift

```
if UIDevice.current.model.hasPrefix("iPad") {
    print("iPad")
} else {
    print("iPhone or iPod Touch")
}
```

Also in the 'Other Examples' in Xcode the device model comes back as 'iPad Simulator' so the above tweak should sort that out.

Comment: Maybe Apple updated the simulator to say something like "iPad simulator" or "iPad 2.1" or something... if that's the case you could use `hasSuffix:@"iPad"` instead of `isEqualToString@"iPad"`... your best bet is to Log the device model that simulator does return and go from there...

Answer (score 16):

Be Careful: If your app is targeting iPhone device only, iPad running with iphone compatible mode will return false for below statement:

```
#define IPAD     UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
```

The right way to detect physical iPad device is:

```
#define IS_IPAD_DEVICE      ([(NSString *)[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPad"])
```

Answer (score 11):

**Many Answers are good but I use like this in swift 4**

1. Create Constant

   ```
   struct App {
       static let isRunningOnIpad = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? true : false
   }
   ```
2. Use like this

   ```
   if App.isRunningOnIpad {
       return load(from: .main, identifier: identifier)
   } else {
       return load(from: .ipad, identifier: identifier)
   }
   ```

**Edit:**  **As Suggested Cœur simply create an extension on UIDevice**

```
extension UIDevice {
    static let isRunningOnIpad = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? true : false
}
```

Comment: Why bothering with an `App` struct when you can do the same with an `UIDevice` extension?

Answer (score 8):

Many ways to do that in **Swift**:

We check the model below (we can only do a case sensitive search here):

```
class func isUserUsingAnIpad() -> Bool {
    let deviceModel = UIDevice.currentDevice().model
    let result: Bool = NSString(string: deviceModel).containsString("iPad")
    return result
}
```

We check the model below (we can do a case sensitive/insensitive search here):

```
    class func isUserUsingAnIpad() -> Bool {
        let deviceModel = UIDevice.currentDevice().model
        let deviceModelNumberOfCharacters: Int = count(deviceModel)
        if deviceModel.rangeOfString("iPad",
                                     options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch,
                                     range: Range<String.Index>(start: deviceModel.startIndex,
                                                                end: advance(deviceModel.startIndex, deviceModelNumberOfCharacters)),
                                     locale: nil) != nil {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
   }
```

`UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom` below only returns iPad if the app is for iPad or Universal. If it is an iPhone app being ran on an iPad then it won't. So you should instead check the model. :

```
    class func isUserUsingAnIpad() -> Bool {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
   }
```

This snippet below does not compile if the class does not inherit of an `UIViewController`, otherwise it works just fine. Regardless `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` only returns iPad if the app is for iPad or Universal. If it is an iPhone app being ran on an iPad then it won't. So you should instead check the model. :

```
class func isUserUsingAnIpad() -> Bool {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a need to rewrite old answers to questions tagged Objective-C to swift.

Comment: I definitely think that my answer is useful because firstly all answers are scattered on stack overflow. Secondly what worked with older versions of iOS does not correctly work sometimes with iOS 8 and above. So I tested these solutions and this answer can be highly useful. So I do not agree with you at all.

Comment: On top of that the syntax is different in Swift. So it is always useful for everybody to do an intelligent copy paste of the answer and understanding the specific up-to-date nuts and bolts.

Comment: [This answer is being discussed on meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298419/)

Answer (score 8):

*

> **In swift 3.0**

*

```
 if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        //pad
    } else if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        //phone
    } else if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .tv {
        //tv
    } else if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .carPlay {
        //CarDisplay
    } else {
        //unspecified
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

In **Swift 4.2** and Xcode 10

```
if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
    //This is iPhone
} else if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .pad { 
    //This is iPad
} else if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .tv {
    //This is Apple TV
}
```

If you want to detect specific device

```
let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
    if (screenHeight >= 667) {
        print("iPhone 6 and later")
    } else if (screenHeight == 568) {
        print("SE, 5C, 5S")
    } else if(screenHeight<=480){
        print("4S")
    }
} else if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .pad { 
    //This is iPad
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check the rangeOfString to see of the word iPad exists like this.

```
NSString *deviceModel = (NSString*)[UIDevice currentDevice].model;

if ([deviceModel rangeOfString:@"iPad"].location != NSNotFound)  {
NSLog(@"I am an iPad");
} else {
NSLog(@"I am not an iPad");
}
```

Comment: `["I am not an iPad" rangeOfString:@"iPad"].location != NSNotFound` returns true.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another Swifty way:

```
//MARK: -  Device Check
let iPad = UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad
let iPhone = UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone
@available(iOS 9.0, *) /* AppleTV check is iOS9+ */
let TV = UIUserInterfaceIdiom.TV

extension UIDevice {
    static var type: UIUserInterfaceIdiom 
        { return UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom }
}
```

Usage:

```
if UIDevice.type == iPhone {
    //it's an iPhone!
}

if UIDevice.type == iPad {
    //it's an iPad!
}

if UIDevice.type == TV {
    //it's an TV!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM () == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad)
 {
            print("This is iPad")
 }else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM () == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.phone)
 {
            print("This is iPhone");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated? This is how I do it...

**Swift 4:**

```
var iPad : Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.model.contains("iPad")
}
```

This way you can just say `if iPad {}`

Comment: Note: This question was asked in 2012

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any of these answers meet my need, unless I am fundamentally misunderstanding something.

I have an app (originally an iPad app) that I want to run both on an iPad and on the Mac, under Catalyst. I'm using the plist option to scale the Mac interface to match the iPad, but would like to migrate to AppKit if that is reasonable. When running on a Mac, I believe that all of the aforementioned approaches tell me that I'm on an iPad. The Catalyst fake-out is pretty thorough.

For most concerns I indeed understand that the code should pretend it's on an iPad when thus running on a Mac. One exception is that the rolling picker is not available on the Mac under Catalyst, but is on the iPad. I want to figure out whether to create a UIPickerView or to do something different, *at run time*. Run-time selection is crucial because I want to use a single binary to run both on the iPad and Mac in the long term, while making the best use of the supported UI standards on each.

The APIs give potentially misleading results to the casual pre-Catalyst reader. For example, `[UIDevice currentDevice].model` returns `@"iPad"` when running under Catalyst on a Mac. The user interface idiom APIs sustain the same illusion.

I found that you really need to look deeper. I start with this information:

```
NSString *const deviceModel = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
NSProcessInfo *const processInfo = [[NSProcessInfo alloc] init];
const bool isIosAppOnMac = processInfo.iOSAppOnMac;  // Note: this will be "no" under Catalyst
const bool isCatalystApp = processInfo.macCatalystApp;
```

Then you can combine these queries with expressions like `[deviceModel hasPrefix: @"iPad"]` to sort out the kinds of subtleties I'm facing. For my case, I explicitly want to avoid making a UIPickerView if the indicated `isCatalystApp` is `true`, independent of "misleading" information about the interface idiom, or the illusions sustained by `isIosAppOnMac` and `deviceModel`.

Now I'm curious what happens if I move the Mac app to run over on my iPad sidecar...

Comment: What an oversight by apple! I wonder if it’s a bug? Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

For the latest versions of iOS, simply add `UITraitCollection`:

```
extension UITraitCollection {

    var isIpad: Bool {
        return horizontalSizeClass == .regular && verticalSizeClass == .regular
    }
}
```

and then within `UIViewController` just check:

```
if traitCollection.isIpad { ... }
```

Comment: Does this also work when the iPad-App is in Split Screen Mode? Then the horizontal size class would be compact.