# Differentiate between iPhone & iPad Storyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am working on `Storyboard`. I have 2 story board for iPhone & iPad. So my question is how can I differentiate between these 2 interfaces.

I am share my code what I did:

```
// I am writing this code in AppDelegate Method.

UIStoryboard *loStoryboard ;
if (loStoryboard == [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil])
{
  // iPhone  .....
}
else
{
  // iPad....
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: How is defined `loStoryboard`?

Comment: Why do you want to differentiate? The correct storyboard will automatically be loaded. Also, `loStoryboard` will be nil. Your controller should be able to handle both the iPad and the iPhone storyboard without ugly `if-else` blocks. If you really need to check the device, use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167221/ios-detect-if-user-is-on-an-ipad

Comment: Your code IS working. It does exactly what you asked for. It instanticates the storyboard based on Main_iPhone regardless whether the app is running on an iPhone or iPad. I suggest to go for Muhammet's suggestion. Or David's which is a bit more mature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one.

In your `AppDelegate` method first define this one:

```
#define IPHONE_STORYBOARD_NAME  @"Main_iPhone";
#define IPAD_STORYBOARD_NAME    @"Main_iPad";
```

Then declare this method:

```
+ (NSString *)storyboardName
{
   if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
       return IPHONE_STORYBOARD_NAME;
   } else {
       return IPAD_STORYBOARD_NAME;
   }
}
```

Where you want call this `storyboardName` method

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[AppDelegate storyboardName] bundle:nil];
```

I think this will helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to differentiate interfaces. This code will return you, which device working:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
        //Ipad
}
else
{
        //Ipod-Iphone
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to differentiate scoreboards.We only differentiate in xcode(which scoreboard for which interface):

Deployment Info -> Main Interface -> storyboardname
Or Programatically you can differ by:

```
  #define interfaceType    UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()

    #define IPAD     UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

    if ( interfaceType == IPAD ) {
    /* do for iPad. */

    } else {

    `enter code here`
    }
```