# How to add xib for iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios7

I have created my app for iPhone and I have one xib. If I run my app on iPad simulator, it appears in left top corner.I want to add one more xib for iPad so that when I run iPhone simulator it will run iPhone xib and when i run iPad simulator it will run iPad xib. How can I do that?

Comment: Simple, Just add xib for iPad then put a condition check in appDelegate.m for checking whether device is iPhone or iPad. Then load that respective xib file. Here is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167221/ios-detect-if-user-is-on-an-ipad) for that condition check for device.

Comment: In order to create new .xib file I have to create .h and .m files. Is there a way not to create new .h .m files?

Comment: Yes, Just right click on any .h or .m file then you will have a option to add new file, click that option. Then a menu will pop-up with lot's of option to choose. So go with the one that will provide you xib file only. Also you really need to go for basic's first.

Answer (score 0):

To create only a Xib file just follow this.

FIle->New ->File...

In the window that appears click the User Interface under IOS u can see a Empty UIBuilder file.

click it then click next and give it the appropriate classfile name for ipad or iphone

Answer (score 0):

First create a new xib for IPAD and while giving the name of the nib file provide the XIB file name created for IPAD.

```
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
HomeScreenController *homeScreenController = [[HomeScreenController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeScreenController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:homeScreenController animated:YES];

}else {
  enter code here
}
```