# Is there a way to perform a method on on specific devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am trying to hide a button on certain devices.  Is there a 'if' statement i could use or something?

thanks in advance

Comment: You want to know specific devices, or you want to categorise them based on some criteria like screen size or iOS version?

Comment: specific device i thought. could it be one with screen size?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167221/ios-detect-if-user-is-on-an-ipad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you can detect specific device, but you can always categorise based on sizes using `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height`.

You can check for the heights and decide the class of device

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
 {
   if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height > 666.0f) {
      //iphone 6/6+
   }
 else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
 {
     //iPhone 5/5C/5S
 }
 else
 {
     //iphones of lower height(3GS/4/4S)
 }
}
else
{
    // its an iPad
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You can get the current device by calling `[UIDevice currentDevice]`.

[Here is the class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/systemVersion)

There are methods for specific iOS versions, models, or you can distinguish between iPad and iPhone. Here is some example code I have in one of my projects.

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
   //Do stuff for iPad
}
```