# Swift nonUniversal storyboard (Without Auto-Layout)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

Hey there i want to make my app look different on other iPhones so i want to make storyboards for every iDevices is it possible ??

(Without Auto-Layout) Thanks

Comment: Possible, but I'd advise against it. I know of a crude method to do it, and that's by querying your view controller's width and height so you can infer the device that it's running at.

It might be fruitful to study up on the `UITraitCollection` which contains size class information that you can use to determine what device you're running. For instance, iPhone 6+ have a size class "regular" that other iphones don't have in orientations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to create storyboards for every device that you want. However it is very tedious as compared to having 1 universal storyboard or two storyboards if you want different designs for iPad and iPhone.

Alternatively, you could also use code to detect whether it is an iPad or iPhone, check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167221/ios-detect-if-user-is-on-an-ipad). As for different sizes for the iPhone, you can do a manual check of the size of the scene and adjust accord.