# iOS universal app different functions iPhone vs iPad?

Tags: iphone, xcode, function, ipad, universal

Does anyone know if you can have different functions or activities in your app on the phone vs pad?
For some games/educational, some activities/functions work better on a larger screen. Does apple allow some activities to be limited on the phone side for a universal app?

I would like to know if apple allows iPhone and iPad not to match exactly in terms of functionality in a universal app.

thanks
SW

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want just to write different code for iPhone / iPad? If so, you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167221/ios-detect-if-user-is-on-an-ipad) answer and then just use different implementations for functions

Comment: Thank you, yes I currently do this now. I just want to know if apple allows iPhone and iPad not to match exactly in terms of functionality.